# Computing and isotopy of curves in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: numerical-analysis-of-pde

Imagine a piece of string in the ocean moving gently with the currents; the string bends but does not change its length.

The (stationary) string can be modelled by a unit speed curve:

$$[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$$

The motion of the string, say from time 0 to time 1, can be modelled by an *isotopy*:

$$\alpha : [0,1]^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$$

where $\alpha(-,0)$ and $\alpha(-,1)$ are the positions of the string at time 0 and time 1, respectively. To ensure that the length of the string is constant in the intermediate times, $\alpha$ must satisfy:

$$
\frac \partial {\partial t}  \left\lvert\frac {\partial \alpha} {\partial s}\right\rvert = 0
$$

equivalently:

$$
\frac {\partial \alpha} {\partial s}  \cdot \frac {\partial^2 \alpha} {\partial s \partial t} = 0
$$

Thinking of a deforming string, it is intuitively clear that an isotopy exists but is far from unique.

Question 1: What sort of extra conditions might be imposed that would guarantee the existence of a unique isotopy (assuming any reasonable differentiability conditions).

Question 2: How does one go about (numerically, I assume) solving such a system of equations?

Question 3:
As a partial answer to question 1, define a metric on the set of unit length curves in $\mathbb{R}^3$. The motion of the string is a path in this space. One could require that this path be of minimal in the sense that it follows a geodesic. I feel that such a minimal isotopy would be unique. What is an appropriate metric? Is there a simple equation that characterizes such paths (with respect to that metric)? How can I compute such a path, given the endpoints?

Comment: For Question 1, you might define what it means for the isotopy to be "efficient", and then ask for the most efficient isotopy possible. This *might* result in a unique solution. Also, a simpler condition ensuring constant length is to just require that for all times t the curve is unit speed.

Comment: I added a third question that proposes a candidate for an "efficient" isotopy (one that follows a geodesic in a metric space of unit length paths). That might address the existence/uniqueness question, if I can nail down an appropriate metric. Still, that leaves the question of how to find solutions (i.e. compute minimal paths). Any ideas?

Comment: I'll just mention that the efficiency need not be expressed in terms of minimizing *the lengths of paths*. (For all I know, there may be a theorem that says: "For all minimization problems, there is a metric with respect to which it is the same as minimizing length." But a priori that is not clear, and other minimizations may be much easier to implement.)